# Why does the crystal sublime more quickly at the corners where there is a higher vapour gradient?

Tags: physical-chemistry, vapor-pressure, sublimation

[image: Diagram]

> The crystal responds to the larger vapor gradients near the edges by
>   sublimating faster there and thus rounding the crystal.
>
> J. Nelson, *J. Atmos. Sci.*, 1998, **55**, 910-119.

The change in shape according to the gradient makes intuitive sense to me but I can't for the life of me figure out why it does this. Maybe I'm being really foolish here, but surely a higher concentration of vapour at the corners would *decrease* the rate of sublimation there.

Comment: The diagrams here are actually super helpful in answering your question. Thank you for including those figures.

Answer (score 2):

The vapor gradient reflects the fact there is much more space at the corner than in the middle of a face. The vapor builds up near the surface but because there is much more space near a corner, the vapor pressure drops off, where as the vapor pressure near a point on the middle of a face is reinforced by sublimation at points near it.